# Android upgrading the existing app

Tags: android

I am trying to upgrade the existing application by changing the following in the manifest file.
changing From

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

To

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" .
```

I am using the same keystore, but when I attempt to publish the app using the Google Play Developer Console, I am getting an error saying:

**"This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
    All devices that might receive version 1 would receive version 2.
    Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code."**

How can I upgrade my app. Thank you very much in advance .

Comment: Did you change your minSdk or screen size qualifiers in your manifest?

Comment: Are you sure you deactivated the old apk in Google Play?

Comment: No I just changed the version code and Version name.Do I need to change them.

Comment: @ raghav sood, Yes it is Deactivated

Comment: No, you don't need to. I was just thinking of reasons devices could be eligible for multiple apks.  Are you using the simple or advanced publishing tabs?  If you're using advanced, try switching to simple and activating the latest apk.  This will deactivate the old one which should remove the conflict.

Comment: Its in simple mode only and if I switch to version 2 in google play I am not getting this error.

Comment: The point is not to just get rid of the error. Someone might actually need to publish a version in Draft mode in order to test the in-app purchase mechanism. How could someone do that? Thanks!

Comment: How to switch back in "Simple Mode". Please help me.

Answer (score 41):

I did the mistake to switch to "advanced" mode and it saved the App as draft somehow.
Seems the developer console doesn't like that.

**Delete the App, switch back to "Simple Mode" and upload the .apk again.**

This worked for me.

The advanced mode is for uploading and managing multiple apks for the same application. 
Simple mode is for uploading single apks so in most cases it should be suitable.

Comment: Best Answer..... test in Beta and then promote to Production... but be in Simple Mode and Allow Google handle the Archive and Promotion for you.  Then the app version shows up right away in the store. In advanced mode... you have to do the steps and it can get hung up.

Answer (score 16):

I ran in the same problem just tonight. All I had to do was to `Archive` the previous version and the draft message disappeared and a button to `Publish` the new version appeared.

Comment: @SimonVeloper Please do not ask people to accept or vote for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Ya i got the same issue then, i did this and resolved the issue:-

Just deactivate the previous apk from the prod, and then upload new 
apk and publish it. It worked for me hope will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to delete the newly uploaded APK and switch to "Simple Mode" to publish an update if you're presented with above message. The wording may not be ideal, but it's telling you that you have two *active* APKs with different version codes, even though one is still in draft status, and that is something you don't want if you intend to serve different APKs to different devices. This is also indicated in the "Production" tab at the top, where it will display both the version code of the existing APK as well as the in-draft update.

Generally speaking, you should only be interested in multiple active APKs if you actually serve dedicated APKs to specific devices. Most apps just consist of a single, generic APK though. So assuming that is the case:

To activate your update (and thus publish the updated APK):

1. Click *Deactivate* next to the currently published APK.
2. Promote your update to *Production* (i.e. promote it to *Beta* first, and to *Production* from there).
3. Hit *Publish APK* at the top of the page.

Following these steps, you'll notice only a single version code remains in the "Production" tab and that the error message disappears. Once you've completed the last step, you'll be able to switch back to Simple Mode as you please.

Comment: But what if I want to promote my Beta to prod in a staged rollout? In that case, I don't want to deactivate the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the page helped hide this message.

I got this error when I had to use Advanced mode to activate single APK. I tried switching to simple mode to activate same APK but it didn't help.