# error while uploading .apk on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed an app which is already in market, now I am trying to upload new version of that app but every time an error is occurring, can anybody tell me solution I am attaching my screenshot of google play.Below are images[image]

Comment: current is  android:versionCode="8" android:versionName="1.3.2" and the previous which was successfully uploaded was  android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="1.2.1"

Comment: I sent many updated apk to my client and everytime he got same error but he didn't informed me yet now he wants me to fix it and I am unable to find its solution

Comment: change version code as 6 reupload

Comment: thanks for your suggestion let me do it and i'll let you know status

Comment: I just uploaded apk version with version code 5 and version name 1.3.3 and got same error

Comment: just did that also but got the same error

Comment: export code sign identity correct debugkeystore file?

Comment: yes that is also correct

Comment: try this stack post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731529/android-upgrading-the-existing-app/14924784#14924784

Answer (score 0):

In Google play they maintain the Hierarchy of version code.
In your case you published version 5 apk already if you want to upgrade just change the new apk version to 6 and upload it to Google play.You can't directly jump from 5 to 8 version.

Thanks...

Comment: I just uploaded apk version with version code 5 and version name 1.3.3 and got same error